# Python Pyramid framework: Unable to include another .py file

Tags: python, pyramid

Newbie in Pyramid framework. I'm trying to include `scrapers.py` file in my `views.py` file.

Here's my dir

```
root
 -static/
 -templates/
 __init__.py
 views.py
 scrapers.py
```

`scrapers.py`

```
def hello():
    h=[1,2,3,4]
    return h
```

`views.py`

```
from pyramid.view import view_config
from scrapers import *

@view_config(route_name='home', renderer='templates/mytemplate.jinja2')
def my_view(request):
    h=hello()
    return {'project': 'news-aggregator','h':h}
```

However, I'm getting the following error.

```
from scrapers import *
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'scrapers'
```

I have no idea why is it showing this error. My IDE seems to be detecting the file, but for some reason pyramid seems to be not. Do I have to include something else?

Comment: Did you try `from root.scrapers import *` or `from .scrapers import *` ?

Comment: @LucasVazquez and Chris Yes, it did. Thanks. I feel like an idiot now haha